# How divide values in one multidimensional array by values in another

Tags: php, arrays

I have two multidimensional array, I need to divide values in one with the values in another, and put the results into a third multidimensional array. I started from this example [here](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/how-to-divide-values-in-one-array-by-values-in-another/88733) but, as I said, I have multidimensional array.

```
$arrayOne =
array(63) [
[0]=> [
        'PROD ONE',
        'CITY ONE',
        2,
        4,
        1,
        2,
        0,
        1,
        0,
    ]....,
    ,];
$arrayTwo =
array(63) [
[0]=> [
        'PROD ONE',
        'CITY ONE',
        8, // need to divide these values by the corrispective ones in $arrayOne
        20,
        23,
        0,
        12,
        0,
        0,
    ],....,];
the result should be another array 
$arrayThree =
array(63) [
[0]=> [
        'PROD ONE',
        'CITY ONE',
        4, /* arrayTwo 8 / 2 arrayOne... */
        5,
        23,
        2,
        0,
        12,
        0,
    ],...
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please edit you question to make it more concise.

Comment: Please put you initial array then just you effort and what is your expected output.?

Comment: I added my expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear where you want to go with this.

This should get you all the values:  `$key, $k, and $v`

```
foreach ($arrayOne as $key => $value) {
  foreach($value as $k => $v){

  }
}
```